# Fetch first charge of a customer in stripe

Tags: ruby

I am reading stripe documentation and I want to fetch the first charge of the a customer. Currently I am doing

```
charge_list = Stripe::Charge.list(
  {
    customer: "cus_xxx"
  },
  "sk_test_xxxxxx"
)
first_charge = charge_list.data.last
```

Since stripe api returns the charges list in sorted order with the most recent charges appearing first. But I don't think it is a good approach. Can anyone help me with how can I fetch the first charge by a customer or how can I sort the list with descending order of created date so that I could get the first object from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no reverse order sorting [feature](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/subsequent) in stripe API.

Also remember the first charge may not be on the first page result set, so you have to iterate using [#auto_paging_each](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#pagination).

A quick possible solution:

```
charge_list = Stripe::Charge.list(
  {customer: "cus_xxx", limit: 100 }, # limit 100 to reduce request
  "sk_test_xxxxxx")

first_charge = nil
charge_list.auto_paging_each {|c| first_charge = c }
```

You may want to persist the result somewhere since it is a heavy operation.

**But the cleanest solution IMO would be to store all charge records into your DB and make subsequent queries against it.**

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I didn't want to update the database there for I added this piece of code in a background job.

Comment: Happy to help @MuhammadAli! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.